# Undefined index error when printing $row['id']

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

The ID column is blank
The lines to display the Glyphs produce an error "Undefined index: id in ...".
The data from 'clubs' displays correctly.
I have cribbed the code below from a public example as I try and teach myself PHP and modified it for something that is useful to me (minor mods) but cannot figure out how to stop the undefined index error.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clubs";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){                        
echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>#</th>";
echo "<th>ClubID</th>";
echo "<th>Club Name</th>";
echo "<th>Active</th>";
echo "<th>Cal Year</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";

echo "<tbody>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ClubID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ClubName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ActiveClub'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['CalendarYr'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span 
class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span 
class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span 
class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";  
                  
echo "</table>";
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
} else
{echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
}
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: The error message means there is **no** id column in the table. May be it's called something else, like Id

Comment: Thanks for that. Dumb mistake on my part converting from the origional